# Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit

Tags: logstash

I am trying to run logstash on Windows.

Just installed [Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html#license-lightbox). Then ran logstash as descirbed [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-windows.html).

Also validated the java install as described in the [same page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-windows.html#running-logstash-windows-validation).

And then when I run [logstash manually](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-windows.html#running-logstash-windows-manual), it first started, but then immediately shutdown, spitting this right on my face.

What am I missing?

```
PS D:\Vivek\Softwares\logstash-7.12.0-windows-x86_64\logstash-7.12.0> .\bin\logstash.bat -f .\config\syslog.conf
Using JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16
WARNING, using JAVA_HOME while Logstash distribution comes with a bundled JDK
2021-04-10T09:47:38.036+05:30 [main] WARN FilenoUtil : Native subprocess control requires open access to the JDK IO subsystem
Pass '--add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED' to enable.
Sending Logstash logs to D:/Vivek/Softwares/logstash-7.12.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.12.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-04-10T09:47:48,897][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: D:\Vivek\Softwares\logstash-7.12.0-windows-x86_64\logstash-7.12.0\config\log4j2.properties
[2021-04-10T09:47:48,905][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.12.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 16+36-2231 on 16+36-2231 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2021-04-10T09:47:48,995][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2021-04-10T09:47:49,259][INFO ][logstash.config.source.local.configpathloader] No config files found in path {:path=>"D:/Vivek/Softwares/logstash-7.12.0-windows-x86_64/logstash-7.12.0/config/syslog.conf"}
[2021-04-10T09:47:49,263][ERROR][logstash.config.sourceloader] No configuration found in the configured sources.
[2021-04-10T09:47:49,415][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-04-10T09:47:54,462][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2021-04-10T09:47:54,471][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at D_3a_.Vivek.Softwares.logstash_minus_7_dot_12_dot_0_minus_windows_minus_x86_64.logstash_minus_7_dot_12_dot_0.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(D:\Vivek\Softwares\logstash-7.12.0-windows-x86_64\logstash-7.12.0\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:89) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: Your log says that logstash could not find any pipeline configuration file, `No configuration found in the configured sources`. Try to pass the full path of your configuration file in the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message "No config files found in path" indicates that when logstash had finished reading all the configuration files it did not have any configuration. That could because your syslog.conf is empty, or it contains invalid UTF-8 characters (so it was skipped), or possibly logstash  was unable to read it.

If you add `--log.level debug` to the command line you should get a "Reading config file" message for that file. If you do not then logstash was unable to find it (e.g. it does not exist or the directory is not readable by the user running logstash).

Answer (score 1):

have you created these files as root? if yes, you have to

```
chown logstash:logstash ./yourpipelie/*.conf
```